# How do you make a tab logo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you make a custom logo on your tab next to the website's title?
Every time I look at the tabs on the top of my browser window I see a logo next to the website's title and I think "I wonder how you make one of those".

Comment: google "favicon" ...

Comment: I would disagree that this is a dup of the suggested link from @Liam as this is asked in a way so as to point back to what a favicon is where as the asker in the pointed to question already knew what a favicon was. This could be a helpful reference to others that are also confused as to what the little logo in the browser is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a *[favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)*.  You can specify one in your site's code by putting this in the `<head>` section of your website's pages:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Where `favicon.ico` links to the actual file you'd like to use.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a favicon, you will usually have to save it as an .ico file. 
Save it in the same directory you would save you index file in.

Comment: +1 This will also work but it's best to put a link into your head.